# Future getting timed out on getting the akka http response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, concurrent.futures

m new to the concept of Futures and i'm getting a Future timed out exception when i'm trying to retrieve a HTTPResponse.

```
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = sampleUrl).withHeaders(Authorization(validCredentials)))
    val timeout = 2.seconds
    responseFuture.flatMap { resp => resp.entity.toStrict(timeout) }.map { strictEntity => strictEntity.data.utf8String }
```

It works as intended for sometime on the cluster where its hosted and crashes, when I check the logs. It says Future timed out after 2 seconds. how do I correct this?

Comment: Change `val timeout = 2.seconds` to something like `val timeout = 5.seconds` ?

Comment: I started with 5000.milliseconds and then changed to 2.seconds. Would increasing the timeout to like 10.seconds solve this or make it worse?

Comment: Make what worse ? Increasing the timeout threshold will result in less timeout errors.

Comment: How long does `sampleUrl` normally take to respond when you make the request using `curl` for example? Setting a timeout value is a trade off. Too high and your client will have to wait for a long time if the server is slow or hung. Too low and you’ll get more timeout errors.

Comment: It pretty much depends on what you're doing, sometime a timeout of 2 seconds is pretty high, sometimes a timeout of 30 seconds is not enough. So it pretty much depends on what you're doing inside the `Future`.

Comment: I'm trying to get a value from configMap in our test cluster. and it works pretty fast when i make a request using curl or use postman. This works great when i run it through localhost but its inconsistent when hosted on the server.

Comment: Your issue in on the server side (or perhaps network/routing to the server): the response is not received in time, so it times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `sampleUrl` is not consistently responding within 2 seconds. By default HTTP clients wait for up to 60 seconds before they fail to receive a response. Perhaps, you could set the Future timeout on the similar lines at 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Pritish  I'll test this out and check how its responding.